# vb.net textbox marker that detects the empty textbox

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a project that will detect which textbox is empty and not

```
If txtInterviewee.Text = String.Empty Or txtInterviewed.Text = String.Empty Or txtValidated.Text = String.Empty Or _
             txtResidence.Text = String.Empty Or dtpValidated.Text = String.Empty Or txtLastName.Text = String.Empty Or _
             txtFirstName.Text = String.Empty Or txtMiddleName.Text = String.Empty Or txtAddress.Text = String.Empty Or _
             cmbGender.Text = String.Empty Or cmbCivilStatus.Text = String.Empty Or dtpBirthDay.Text = String.Empty Or _
             txtBirthPlace.Text = String.Empty Or txtCitizenship.Text = String.Empty Then
            MsgBox("Must fill the following Fields")
        End If
```

if any of the textbox is empty I want it to be marked or something so the user will know which textbox needs to be filled.

Comment: Look at the ErrorProvider component or concat a message from a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through all the text boxes in the form and check if they are empty or not. Something like this:

```
 For Each box As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
     If box.Text = String.Empty Then
         box.Text = "This is empty!!"
     End If
 Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could write a function like this

```
Function CheckIfBoxEmpty(ByVal txt as TextBox) as Boolean
     if string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt.Text) Then
         ' Optionally insert a message here .....
         txt.Focus()
         return True
     else
         return False
     End If
End Function
```

Then you could call this function for each of your textboxes that you want to monitor

```
Dim isEmpty as Boolean = False
if Not isEmpty Then isEmpty = CheckIfBoxEmpty(txtInterviewee)
if Not isEmpty Then isEmpty = CheckIfBoxEmpty(txtInterviewed)
if Not isEmpty Then isEmpty = CheckIfBoxEmpty(txtValidated)
...and so on for the other textboxes
```

The code above is recommended if you have some textboxes to be checked and some that don't need to be checked. Instead, if all of your textboxes on the form are to be checked then a simple for each loop is more appropriate

```
For Each tbox in Me.Controls.OfType(of TextBox)
     if CheckIfBoxEmpty(tbox) Then
         Exit For
     End If
Next
```

In these ways the CheckIfBoxEmpty function will set the focus to the empty textbox and return True to signal that an empty textbox has been found and you could stop your search for it. If you really need to send a message to your user you could add it before setting the textbox focus using a MessageBox or better an ErrorProvider object that blinks next to your faulty textbox.